# How can I insert some R code (as just plain text) into LaTeX

Tags: r, code

I'm writing a report for a course and we need to include our R script in the appendix of our report (It just needs to be like it would in a plain text file, just in LaTeX. How can I insert this? My document class is `MastersDoctoralThesis`.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Please be so kind, to show us, what you have tried yourself, by adding a MWE.  In this case, please also use the [search function](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=R+code), there are plenty of examples.

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward way is to use a `verbatim` environment.

```
\begin{verbatim}
Whatever
      characters ^^&TY&(*YD
          in whichever
              layout
\end{verbatim}
```

[image]